# Retain characters in a string which match a regex

Tags: java, string

Is there a way to create a string which retains characters from an input string which are matches a regex?

I want to retain all characters which are either `'_'` (underscore), or `[a-z]` or `[A-Z]`. And delete all the other characters.

I am looking for a some function like:

```java
String replaceAll(String inputString, String inputRegex);
```

For example:

```java
{
    ...
    String inputString = "aa@b#$cd12";
    String inputRegex = "[_a-zA-Z]";
    String outputString = replaceAll(inputString, inputRegex);
    System.out.println(outputString);
}
```

Output Printed - `aabcd`

Comment: I am confused by your question as you have not shown the code.  Are you wanting to know how to use `String.replaceAll` or are you wanting to know how to do a `regex` which will not all **but** the regex?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I want to know if there is a function such as String.replaceAll, which consumes two strings - an input string and an output string -- say String.replaceAll(inputString, inputRegex).

Comment: You mean `String newString = inputString.replaceAll (inputRegex, ""); which will replace chars found in your inputRegex with blanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your regex to describe all the characters *not* in your set (note the caret ^ character).

```
String inputString = "aa@b#$cd12";
String inputRegex = "[^_a-zA-Z]+";
String outputString = inputString.replaceAll(inputRegex, "");
```

Comment: I have added a vote up, but it does not count as my profile is below 15 reputation. I really appreciate the simple solution.